# Prove that the unitary closed ball of $l_1 (\mathbb N)$ is closed in $l_2 (\mathbb N)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that the unitary closed ball of $l_1 (\mathbb N)$ is closed in $l_2 (\mathbb N)$.

My attempt: $$\text{Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} $ be a sequence such that }\sum_i^\infty  |x_{n_i}| \le 1 \ \text{and} \lim_{n\to \infty  } x_n = x \text { in $ l_2(\mathbb N)$}$$
If we had that the unitary ball was not closed, then we could have $x$ such that $\sum_i^\infty  |x_{i}| > 1$ and that:
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \ , \exists p \in \mathbb N:n>p \implies  \sum_i^\infty (x_{n_i}-x_i)^2 <\epsilon  $$ After playing with this expression, I couldn't find any contradiction.

Comment: $\ell_p(\mathbb{R})$ and $\ell_p(\mathbb{N})$are not the same thing! From your OP, one inferres that you are dealing with $\ell_p(\mathbb{N})$, which is the space of sequences $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_n|x(n)|^p<\infty$.

Comment: I had it written R in my linear analysis notes, dind't know they were diferent.

Comment: The is all right. It is just that $\ell_p(A)$ is received to the space of all $x:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n\in A}|x(n)|^p<\infty$, where the sum is meant as running over all all finite subsets of $A$, that is $\sum_{n\in A}|x(n)|^p=\sup\{\sum_{n\in J}|x(n)|^p: J\subset A, J\, finite\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})\subset\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$, this the unit $\|\;\|_1$-ball is contained in $\ell_2$.

Suppose $(x_k, x: k\in\mathbb{N})\subset \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ such that

1. $\sum_n|x_k(n)|\leq 1$,
2. $\|x_k-x\|^2_2=\sum_n|x_k(n)-x(n)|^2\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Condition (2) implies
$$|x_k(n)-x(n)|\leq \|x_k-x\|_2,\qquad k,n\in\mathbb{N}$$
Hence
$$\lim_k x_k(n)=x(n),\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
The conclusion can be obtained by an application of [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Standard_statement), for
$$\sum_n|x(n)|=\sum_n\lim_k|x_k(n)|\leq\liminf_k\sum_n|x_k(n)|\leq 1$$
by condition (1).

Comment: I'm sorry, why do you claim that: $|x_k(n)−x(n)|≤∥x_k−x∥_2   \ k,n∈N$ ?

Comment: @RicardoMM: no, I did mean $|x_k(n)-x(n)|\leq\|x_k-x\|_2$, and that is rather obvious: $|a(n)|\leq \sqrt{|a^2(1)+\ldots + |a^2(n)|+\ldots}$

Answer (score 1):

Step I. The closed unit ball in $\ell_1(\mathbb N)$ is a subset of the closed unit ball of $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$.

Step II. If $x^n=(x_k^n)\in\ell_1(\mathbb N)$, $\|x^n\|_1\le 1,$ and $(x^n)$ is $\ell_1-$convergent to $x=(x_k)$, then clearly $x_k^n\to x_k$, for all $k$.
Also, $(x^n)$ is $\ell_1-$Cauchy. But,
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}|x^m_k-x_k^n|^2
=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}|x^m_k-x_k^n||x^m_k-x_k^n| 
\le 2\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}|x^m_k-x_k^n|,
$$
since $|x^m_k-x_k^n|\le 2$, for all $m,n,k$. Thus $(x^n)$ is $\ell_2-$Cauchy, and hence is $\ell_2-$convergent.

Say $\|x^n-y\|_2\to 0$, where $y=(y_k)$, then clearly $x_k^n\to y_k$, for all $k$, and hence $y=x$.

But $x$ is in the unit closed ball of $\ell^1$.